# Casting model in asp razor view inside javascript string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

My view generates some js code. I need to cast my Model to interface type to get some properties.

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var js_array = [];
@for (var i = 0; i < ( Model as MyProject.Models.IMyInterface ).PropertyList.Count; i++) {
    <text>
        js_array['@( Model as MyProject.Models.IMyInterface ).PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
    </text>
}
</script>
```

I got:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var js_array = [];
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
js_array['MyProject.Models.MyModelType.PropertyList[i].id'] = {};
</script>
```

But I need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var js_array = [];
js_array['1'] = {};
js_array['2'] = {};
js_array['3'] = {};
js_array['4'] = {};
js_array['5'] = {};
js_array['6'] = {};
js_array['7'] = {};
js_array['8'] = {};
</script>
```

As you can see this display type instead of value...

Can you tell me why and how can I fix it?

Comment: The reason why is because the `@()` is a special block that only parses what's contained in the `()`. Your code has only the class in the `()` and so it calls `ToString` on the class and then the `.PropertyList...` is assumed to be just regular output because it's no longer under control of the `@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're missing a couple of parentheses.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < ( Model as MyProject.Models.IMyInterface ).PropertyList.Count; i++) {
    <text>
        js_array['@( (Model as MyProject.Models.IMyInterface).PropertyList[i].id )'] = {};
    </text>
}
```

I would make it a bit more readable like:

```
@foreach ( var property in ((MyProject.Models.IMyInterface)Model).PropertyList ) {
    <text>
        js_array['@(property.id )'] = {};
    </text>
}
```

And if your model implements the interface then you don't even need the cast, making it:

```
@foreach ( var property in Model.PropertyList ) {
    <text>
        js_array['@(property.id)'] = {};
    </text>
}
```